# Databricks link to cells using markdown

Tags: databricks

From Databricks documentation, I understand that we can link to other notebooks from a notebook as below:

```
%md
<a href="$./myNotebook">Link to notebook in same folder as current notebook</a>
<a href="$../myFolder">Link to folder in parent folder of current notebook</a>
<a href="$./myFolder2/myNotebook2">Link to nested notebook</a>
```

How can I link to a cell in the same notebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in cell, note the URL - it has the form like:

```
https://<url>/?o=147804121238830#notebook/128991821126784/command/252704521328130
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                  this is cell id
```

When you change the cell that id will change correspondingly. So you can link to a cell using this:

```markdown
%md

Go to <a href="#notebook/128991821126784/command/252704521328130">this cell</a>
```

Note that we're using HTML here, because standard Markdown links (`[this cell](#notebook/...)`) would be rendered with `target="_blank"` and open in new tab.

Comment: Do you know how to make it not open a new tab when you click the link? I mean just make it scroll to the cell on the same page.

Comment: Whoa, blind me. Thanks you asked - only after a year I realized it IS an anchor and you can scroll to another cell in the same page by just linking to it - updated the answer.